# Write content from server if JavaScript is not enabled

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project that by default loads content via AJAX.

I want it to check if the user (or SE bot) has JS disabled, and if so display the content statically via PHP.

Is there a way to do this? I don't think noscript tag would work here, as the page would be empty to the non JS users or bots.

Also doing a redirect to a different page it doesn't make sense to me, as the links to the original page will not be taken into consideration by search engines and will not be able to index that page as they will be redirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)? You could make the plain html page the default and then use JS to hide or replace the clunky bits with your fancy AJAX controls. You end up with only one page per view which dynamically upgrades itself. URLs are safe to pass around too.

Comment: That is the one that most makes sense... The only problem is that I will use server resources twice. One to display the non js version that after will be hidden by javacript and the second time to display the javascript one. Two queries for the same result

Comment: @Hugo are you really worried about the load against your server? And if it *really* does become a problem, could you not cache the output for a few seconds so the second request can be served immediately?

Comment: I agree with the caching, and would also mention that you shouldn't have to run 2 queries to get the same content. Once the content is on the page you can grab it via JS. You can even dump your content in JSON right on the page as global variable, which you can access in window.onload().

Answer (score 4):

There isn't really a way to automatically change to a different page when the user DOESN'T have JavaScript.

What I'd do is to display the non-JS version as default but hava a script on each page that redirects to the AJAX version and sets a cookie so that from then on all pages display the AJAX version right away. Oh, and better keep a noscript tag with a link to the non-AJAX version around in case anything goes wrong, such as someone who already has the cookie disabling JavaScript.

Comment: I agree with leaving the noscript tag after detecting the cookie. Makes all the sense.

I just didnt want to redirect as I would be redirecting the search engine bots also and the pages indexed would be the non js pages. That really annoys me and I will lose the link juice to the ajax pages

Comment: AJAX pages typically don't get indexed at all, so having the non-AJAX pages indexed is exactly what you want - they should have basically  the same content anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `<noscript>` html tag.

The  tag is supported in all major browsers. This includes IE, Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari.

Here's a normal example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```

Here is a variation that uses a `<meta>` redirect tag that will redirect a browser that doesn't support javascript (tested and works):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>Please wait while you're being redirected to the no-script version...
<META http-equiv="refresh" content="1;URL=http://yoursite/index.php?version=noscript">
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two methods to consider, below: (CSS display or DOM node removal)

1) ***CSS:***

Consider css display controls for various nodes that are conditional on JS.

Onload, JavaScript can change the pertinent elements' display style to "none".

- If there is no JS, then the page elements are not hidden.

In your onload init function, set: `elObj.style.display:none;`.

Add noscript links or notice, so that someone who has simply disabled JavaScript can choose to enable it or not, based on what you tell them they are not seeing.

OR

2) ***Node Extraction:***

A second option is to have JavaScript actually remove the redundant nodes onload.

- Bots and Non-JS users will have immediate, non-obtrusive access to the page elements.
- JS users will get the goods delivered by your scripts.

For example, you might have one granddaddy container division to remove, that has a known id, say "nonjs".

A function I use to remove them from memory:

```
XDOM.deleteNode = function(node) {
    if (!node || typeof node != "object") {return;}
    var trashcan = XDOM.getElementById('xdomtrashcan');
    if (!trashcan) {
        trashcan = document.createElement('DIV');
            // quick and dirty property set:
        trashcan.id = 'xdomtrashcan';
        trashcan.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(trashcan);
     }
     trashcan.appendChild(node);
     trashcan.innerHTML = ""; //empty the trash
  };
```

- (XDOM normalizes browser differences. This code uses XDOM.getElementById. Use your favorite cross-browser function instead.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "home" or some other previous page that the user navigates from you can include some javascript to set a cookie.
When the user selects your target page you can then generate either plain HTML or an AJAXy page depending on whether the cookie is set.

A varation on this would be to publish the URL address of a "landing" page which sets (or doesnt set) the cookie with an "onload" script and does an HTML redirect to the page with the data.